# Certificate error

Tags: networking, 16.04, virtualbox, vpn, ssl

I'm working on a virtualbox using ubuntu 16.04, I'm also working off a corporate network. Any and everything that tries to connect to the internet responds with an unknown issuer error. I understand that all my internet traffic goes through the company's VPN and the VPN issues the certificate, now I need to know what to put in a certificate and where to get that info so that my computer trusts my company's server as a certificate issuer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have some kind of malware or settings problem that has messed up IE in your XP VM, or it might be ESET on the host, or it might be a problem with the NAT provider in VirtualBox and you host's NIC driver.  It's hard to tell which though!
First, I'd try resetting your Internet Explorer to it's default settings.  If you have the latest IE, on the Tools menu, Internet options, Advanced tab, and at the bottom, it has a reset button.  If that doesn't help, then I'd scan your VM from one of the online antivirus scanners.  Then I'd try disabling ESET temporarily on the host.  And last would be to update your NIC drivers on the host.

Comment: The VirtualBox program is running Ubuntu while the host computer is windows 7.